# React component setState() and meanwhile the parent component rerender itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I built a React page like this:
[image: page].
The switcher is binded to a callback function from the parent componentA and componentA get this function from top-level page. The callback updates top-level page's state. So when the switcher clicked, then top-level page will rerender the componentA.

The switcher I'm using is a component from React-Switch library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-switch

Then sometimes, when I click the switcher, there will be a warning:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the ReactSwitch component.
```

Here is some code snippet.
In top-level page:

```
    // In the top-level page, there is a state to decide whether or not to apply some data filter
    onSwitcherClicked(event) {
        this.setState({
            applyFilter: event,
    });

    render() {
        const filter = this.state.applyFilter ? '{paths:["/some_filters"],}' : '{paths:["/none"],}';
        return (
            <div>
                <ComponentA
                    filter = {filter}
                    applyFilter = {this.applyFilter}
                    callBack = {this.onSwitcherClicked}
                    />
            </div>
        );
```

In Component A

```
    // Component A
    componentWillMount() {
        // Send some API request according to this.props.filter and load the data
        // So every time the switcher clicked, the page will update the filter and pass some new props to componentA,
        // then ComponentA will remount it self
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DataViewer>
                    {/*A component to display the data*/}
                </DataViewer>
                <Switch onChange={this.props.callBack}
                        checked={this.props.applyFilter}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Here is the error message"

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the ReactSwitch component. 

printWarning warning.js:33
    warning warning.js:57
    React 3
        getInternalInstanceReadyForUpdate
        enqueueSetState
        setState
    $onDragStop react-switch.dev.js:252
    $onMouseUp react-switch.dev.js:277
```

I also copied the code in react-switch.dev.js:252 and react-switch.dev.js:277:

```
// react-switch.dev.js:252
252 this.setState({
253       $isDragging: false,
254       $hasOutline: false
255     });
256     this.$lastDragAt = Date.now();
// switch.dev.js:277
276 ReactSwitch.prototype.$onMouseUp = function $onMouseUp(event) {
277     this.$onDragStop(event);
278     window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.$onMouseMove);
279    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.$onMouseUp);
280  };
```

I guess it's because when I click the switcher, it will reset the its own status. Meanwhile, the parent component's state is changed too. So when the switcher calls setState(), itself has been unmounted. Am I correct? Is there some approach to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't guess, show code (minimal please). The switcher component shouldn't be unmounting even if it's setting state in it's parent component.

Comment: Sure, thank you! I added some code snippet and detail.

Comment: Did you typo your top level page is `const filter = this.applyFilter ? ...` supposed to be `this.state.applyFilter`?

Comment: Sorry! It's a typo. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, but your component structure should look very similar to this kind of thing, in which case you wouldn't be getting that warning. I have a feeling you might be trying to duplicate the source of truth for state instead of just letting it flow down.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [isClicked,setIsClicked] = useState(false);


    return (
        ...
        <Switcher selected={isClicked} onClick={() => setIsClicked(!isClicked)}/>
    )

}
```